# Change single-image upload into batch upload? (help please!)

Tags: actionscript-3, image, air, batch-processing

EDIT: Reworked my code a bit and decided to throw out URLLoader in favor of the File.upload() method.

Now I'm stuck again >_<

Here's the code I currently have, stripped down to bare-bones: https://gist.github.com/1943401

When I drag-drop image files onto my app, here is the trace log that gets returned to me:

```
[object Document] called.
doDragEnter() called.
doDragDrop() called.
file Extension Check = passed
Uploading files: C:\testimage.jpg
addImage() called.
currently uploading: [object File]
Making progress with [object File]..
Making progress with [object File]..
Making progress with [object File]..
Making progress with [object File]..
Making progress with [object File]..
HTTP Response: [HTTPStatusEvent type="httpResponseStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=400 responseURL="http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.xml?key=********REMOVED**********&name=name&title=title"]
onCookieSent() called.
resultsListXML = 
Temp value= 
xmlString Value= 
Upload Complete: [DataEvent type="uploadCompleteData" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 data="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<error><message>No image data was sent to the upload api</message><request>/2/upload.xml</request><method>post</method><format>xml</format><parameters>Filename = testimage.jpg, Upload = Submit Query, key = *********REMOVED********</parameters></error>
"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar to Todds alternative. Basically I had to upload each image asynchronously (one at a time).

So I created an array of images and created an integer (i) counter starting at 0.

```
uploadImage(imagesArray[i]);
```

Each time I uploaded an image the COMPLETE event was called.

within the complete event function the counter was incremented. If the counter was less than the length of the imagesArray I would then
e.g.

```
i++
if (i < imagesArray.length) {
uploadImage(imagesArray[i]);
} else {
//all images have been uploaded.
//reset vars
i = 0;
imagesArray = [];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! I've decided to abandon the URLLoader in favor of File.upload(), however the response I'm getting from the server is "No image data was sent to the upload API". Here's my new code. Do you see anything that looks fishy? if I drag and drop multiple files onto my app now it doesnt crash, but they aren't being uploaded to the 'web either. https://gist.github.com/1943401

Comment: It could possibly be that you need to send a type ByteArray rather than type File to the API.

Answer (score 0):

In your `doDragDrop` method I would first throw your `addImage();` call outside of the for loop, instead of within it, since in `addImage()` you are looping through the files anyways.

If that doesn't improve your problem, you could also consider adding all files to the array/queue like you are, but then only sending them to the server one at a time. On an Event.Complete or IOError I would then call a new function to process the next file in the array/queue.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the reply! I did what you recommended and fixed the loop inside a loop thing (poor craftsmanship of me to do that but live and learn! :) ). I've decided to abandon the URLLoader in favor of File.upload(), however the response I'm getting from the server is "No image data was sent to the upload API". Here's my new code. Any help is appreciated! https://gist.github.com/1943401